# How to catch and handle error in monaco-editor with angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, monaco-editor

I'm using ***angular-monaco-editor*** with my project and I want to restrict the user of saving code that contains errors, I would like to catch if the script typed contains errors so I can create my function based on it!
I dived a little bit before asking but I can't find the event that may help me catch whenever error appears.